# if else condition not working for Javascript

Tags: javascript

here the scenario is , i have created tooltip, and for all the `div` tag i have given different id's , based on their id's it should generate different tool tip.. for that i am using `if else` condition under javascript and checking for `div`'s id, but here code is not going in else if condition: you can check the live example on [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/imchaitanya9/6CBMw/) .. guys plz help me out, and thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Show us code so that we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
     if (event.target.id == "ips") {/*Code*/} 
     else if (event.target.id == "tyu") {/*Code*/} 
     else {/*Code*/}
```

instead of `document.getElementById`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6CBMw/5/)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("ips")` always return the Html div object and its boolean value will be true. comapare for the value.

you need to grab the attribute "id" of target from event and compare it with your div id.

```
 if(event.target.id=="ips")
  {

  $('<div class="tooltip">situated on or affecting the same side</div>')
        .appendTo('body');
  }
  else if(event.target.id=="tyu")
  {

  $('<div class="tooltip">hi i m tooltip</div>').appendTo('body');
  }else....
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong:

```
if(document.getElementById("ips"))
```

This will always be true, since there always is an element with id `ips`. What you want is to compare it with the actual id:

```
var this_id = $(this).attr("id");
if(id === "ips")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/6CBMw/8/

```
    var linkId = $(this).attr('id');
    switch(linkId){
        case 'ips':
            $('<div class="tooltip">situated on or affecting the same side</div>').appendTo('body');
            break;
        case 'tyu':
             $('<div class="tooltip">hi i m tooltip</div>').appendTo('body');
            break;
        default:
             $('<div class="tooltip">hi i m LAST LAST tooltip</div>').appendTo('body');
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**http://jsfiddle.net/6CBMw/13/**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var changeTooltipPosition = function(event) {
      var tooltipX = event.pageX - 8;
      var tooltipY = event.pageY + 8;
      $('div.tooltip').css({top: tooltipY, left: tooltipX});
    };

    var showTooltip = function(event) {
      console.log(event.target);  
      $('div.tooltip').remove();
      if(event.target == document.getElementById('ips'))
      {
          $('<div class="tooltip">situated on or affecting the same side</div>').appendTo('body');
      } else if(event.target == document.getElementById('tyu')){
          $('<div class="tooltip">hi i m tooltip</div>').appendTo('body');
      } else {
          $('<div class="tooltip">hi i m LAST LAST tooltip</div>').appendTo('body');
      }
      changeTooltipPosition(event);
    };

    var hideTooltip = function() {
       $('div.tooltip').remove();
    };

    $('div#ips, div#tyu').bind({
       mousemove : changeTooltipPosition,
       mouseenter : showTooltip,
       mouseleave: hideTooltip
    });

});
```